# ASPNET CORE: Data Protection takes over 3 minutes when first time startup

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, aspnetboilerplate, dpapi

My ASPNET CORE MVC startup is too slow, when I check the log file, there was a task that take over 3 mins as below. Could anyone give me some advice?

```
INFO  2020-10-03 11:06:28,471 [1    ] taProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager - User profile is available. Using 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
INFO  2020-10-03 11:09:50,239 [1    ] IdentityServer4.Startup                  - Starting IdentityServer4 version 3.1.2.0
```

Comment: Does there have lots of data to be protected? Can you post the related code in the startup.cs file? Besides,  whether you are using the DPAPI to protect the data? According to the [ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) document, Windows provides DPAPI for desktop applications but this is unsuitable for web applications. Reference:[Configure ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1)